# Android App crashes on startup while reading objects from java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I am working on my first Android app. It was working fine until I decided to add a functionality to save and load objects and settings on OnCreate and onRestart. After that the app crashes on startup. Here is the setSettings that I call from OnCreate.

```
public void setSettings(){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",0);
    newGame = settings.getBoolean("newGame", true);
    autoDecide = settings.getBoolean("autoDecide", true);
    saved = settings.getBoolean("saved", false);
    if (saved){     
        player1 = readPlayer("Player 1");
        player2 = readPlayer("Player 2");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player1name)).setText(""+player1.name);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player2name)).setText(""+player2.name);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.player1wins)).setText(""+player1.totalWins);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.player2wins)).setText(""+player2.totalWins);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player1life)).setText(""+player1.life);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player2life)).setText(""+player2.life);
    }
}
```

the saved boolean is supposed to be false until I saved things, but I don't think it is working. Here is the readPlayer that it calls where the problem might be.

```
    public Player readPlayer(String loc)  {
    //FileInputStream fis;
        try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream( openFileInput(loc));
        ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(buf);
        Player re = (Player) stream.readObject();
        stream.close();
        buf.close();
        return re;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
            return new Player(loc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return new Player(loc);
}
```

and here is the logCat that I get when it crashes.

```
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{jjcard.app.lifecount/jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.setSettings(Life_counterActivity.java:72)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at jjcard.app.lifecount.Life_counterActivity.onCreate(Life_counterActivity.java:42)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-26 03:49:05.739: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
```

I don't know if you would need the player creation but here it is

```
    public Player(String nameN){
    name = nameN;
    life = 8000;
    totalWins = 0;
    totalLosses = 0;
    wins = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
```

It happens everytime I start it up and I've tried a few things as you can probably see by the code with no success. I tried searching around but I can't find anything. Hope you guys can help.
EDIT: here is line 72 that the LogCat shows is the problem.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player1name)).setText(""+player1.name);
```

So it looks like you are right, it might be making reading an empty object instead of returning a new player like I thought it would. 
 And since I don't know a lot about making writing and reading objects, I just used defaultWriteObject and defaultReadObject

```
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    out.defaultWriteObject();
}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
}
```

**EDIT:** after changing the read/write and trying to check for the name being null, it still doesn't work. I even tried setting the text to a String and it still gives a nullPointerException, so guess it has something do do with the FindViewById(R.id.Player1name), but I don't know exactly what yet. I use different views for different screens using ViewPagerIndicator, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Life_counterActivity.java see line no.72

Answer (score 1):

See the Exception stack trace you posted - it says that the error was `caused by:` the line #72 in `Life_counterActivity.java` - this will give you some indication as to the objects that might be `null`.

Without knowing which line it actually is, it is probably one of the 6 lines that look like this...

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player1name)).setText(""+player1.name);
```

There are 2 possibilities...

1. The object `player1` is null, so you can't ask for its `name`.
2. The `R.id.Player1name` can't be found - this is less likely, but you can't call `setText()` if it does actually return a null object.

Seeing as though its probably `player1` or `player2`, could you please show where you're saving the `Player` object to the file - it looks like it might be creating the object from a file but not populating the variables. Assuming that `Player` implements `Serializable`, could you show the code of `writeObject()` and `readObject()` please. Refer to the [Serializable java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for info on these methods.

So, as a suggestion for your `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods...

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{
    out.writeObject(name);
    out.writeInt(life);
    out.writeInt(totalWins);
    out.writeInt(totalLosses);
    out.writeObject(wins);
}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
    name = (String)in.readObject();
    life = in.readInt();
    totalWins = in.readInt();
    totalLosses = in.readInt();
    wins = (HashMap<String, Integer>) in.readObject();
}
```

Comment: ok, I added what you asked to the question, thanks for the help.

Comment: So, what I would suggest is that you write your own `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods. I have edited my answer to include a suggested solution, which writes out each of the values, and reads them in again. I built this using the example shown in the summary at the top of the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` java docs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but It still crashes at startup. I think I narrowed the issue down to it not being about the player object or player.name being null, but something do actually do with ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Player1name))